# Javascript working on jsfiddle but not wordpress site?

Tags: javascript

This is the code that I want to include on wordpress site: http://jsfiddle.net/EFM9b/1/

The results doesn't display on wordpress site, but it does work in JSfiddle

Comment: How are you including it? Are there any errors in the console? For starters, jQuery must be used with the no-conflict naming in WordPress, i.e. jQuery('...') instead of $('...')

Comment: As noted by tmdesigned, replace `$` with `jQuery` in your script or wrap whole js code with  `( function ($) { /* *** your code *** */ })(jQuery);`.

Comment: @tmdesigned I did use jQuery instead of $. Here is the link to my site - [link](http://34.246.124.138/375-2/). I've changed the code a bit but it works the exact same way as in the jsfiddle. Still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @nmr thanks! tried wrapping it inside as well. doesn't seem to work still

Comment: or look at this [link](http://34.246.124.138/test/) instead. it's simpler as I just used simple code. I do have a theme installed with WP Bakery Page Builder in it. Would that be what's inteferring with it?

Comment: Is your code in `jscript.js` file? I see in developer tools a 404 error while loading it.

Comment: @nmr Thanks for getting back to me! I'm not sure. I tried adding the javascript code directly on the page I was building. Just added to this .js file [link](https://ibb.co/fSQGK6v) but still doesn't seem to work. Am I adding it at the right place?

Comment: In second link you have `jQuery('#style');</p><p>` in JS code. **</p><p>** is not allowed to appear there.

Comment: @nmr ah ok. removed <p></p> within JS code but the code still doesn't seem to work... [link](http://34.246.124.138/test/)

Comment: JS works, class "**active**" is added, but **result** div is `display: none`. Add styles `.result.active { display: block; }`.